# Opacity in IE =S

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, filter, opacity

I've looked at the other questions and still cannot figure this out.

**EDIT**
Here is a HTML page which reproduces my error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN"><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<HTML>
<HEAD><STYLE> 
HTML
{
    min-height: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
}
BODY
{
    min-height: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
}
DIV
{
    min-height: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
}
HTML
{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
BODY
{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
BODY
{
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#abc_content
{
    border-bottom: #666 2px solid;
    border-left: #666 0px solid;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-top: #666 2px solid;
    border-right: #666 0px solid;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#abc_leftbar + #abc_content
{
    margin-left: 210px;
}
.ui-helper-clearfix:after
{
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
}
.ui-helper-clearfix
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.ui-helper-clearfix
{
    display: block;
}
.ui-state-disabled
{
    cursor: default !important;
}
.ui-widget-header
{
    background: #176000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-state-default
{
    border-bottom: #176000 1px solid;
    border-left: #176000 1px solid;
    background-color: #458b11;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: #176000 1px solid;
    border-right: #176000 1px solid;
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default
{
    border-bottom: #176000 1px solid;
    border-left: #176000 1px solid;
    background-color: #458b11;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: #176000 1px solid;
    border-right: #176000 1px solid;
}
.ui-state-disabled
{
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); opacity: .75;
    -moz-opacity: .75;
    -khtml-opacity: .75;
}
.ui-corner-tl
{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
.ui-corner-tr
{
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.ui-corner-bl
{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.paging_full_numbers .ui-button
{
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
.ui-buttonset .ui-button
{
    margin-right: -0.1em !important;
}
.paging_full_numbers
{
    width: 350px !important;
}
.ui-toolbar
{
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    zoom: 1;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.dataTables_paginate
{
    width: auto;
}
.dataTables_wrapper
{
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 120%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.dataTables_wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 302px;
    clear: both;
    _height: 302px;
}
.dataTables_paginate
{
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 20px;
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
}

</STYLE></HEAD>
<BODY><DIV id="abc_content"><DIV id="dd_table_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper"><DIV class="fg-toolbar ui-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix"><DIV id="dd_table_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate fg-buttonset ui-buttonset fg-buttonset-multi ui-buttonset-multi paging_full_numbers">

<SPAN id="dd_table_first" class="first ui-corner-tl ui-corner-bl fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-state-disabled" jQuery1297179778124="2">First</SPAN>

</DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

It works in FF and Chrome, but not in IE (I am using IE 8).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just changed the colors to make it look like i'm changing the opacity. IE fail...

Answer (score 5):

you need to set the `-ms-filter` in IE 8

```
opacity: .70; /* Standard: FF gt 1.5, Opera, Safari */
filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* IE lt 8 */
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=70)"; /* IE 8 */
-khtml-opacity: .70; /* Safari 1.x */
-moz-opacity: .70; /* FF lt 1.5, Netscape */
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. unfortunately it still does not work :(

Comment: is there some browser caching going on? Do you have a url? What I posted should give you opacity in every browser.

Comment: this is the first time the answer that should be right just isnt working for me. i've copied the trace from IE and edited my post with it. it creates an html page with exactly what I have, but the filter does not work on the "First" button (or span, rather).

Comment: Thats because you have `.ui-state-disabled
{
    cursor: default !important;
}` not `down vote
 

you need to set the -ms-filter in IE 8

opacity: .70; /* Standard: FF gt 1.5, Opera, Safari */
filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* IE lt 8 */
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=70)"; /* IE 8 */
-khtml-opacity: .70; /* Safari 1.x */
-moz-opacity: .70; /* FF lt 1.5, Netscape */`

Comment: sorry, i don't quite understand that. here is a more clear example though. could you perhaps modify it with your idea? http://jsfiddle.net/wqTEp/7/

Answer (score 1):

Opacity is not supported in IE8 - You can use MS's gradient filter instead:

```
.className{
opacity: 0.7; 
-ms-filter: "alpha (opacity=70)"; 
filter: alpha (opacity=70);
}
```

Comment: I agree with hunter, the above should defiantly work you may have a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
opacity:.70;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
filter:alpha(opacity=70);
```